Return Flux or List with projected attribute values without the attribute names (so not in document form) in Spring JPA MongoDB @Query
In a MongoDB document with the following structure (represented as a Java POJO):
public class QuestionProfilerSolutionLineDocument {
    private String id;
    private String profilerId;
    private String query;
   //... some other attributes
    private Integer analyticsIndex;
}

I only need the plain analyticsIndex values: I don't need the document format because I want to avoid an unnecessary mapping (i.e: questionDocumentFlux -> questionDocumentFlux.map(question -> question.getAnalyticsIndex)) if possible.
I have the following query with a simple projection to only get the analyticsIndex attribute:
@Query(value = "{ 'profilerId' : ?0, 'analyticsIndex' : { $ne : null } }", fields = "{ 'analyticsIndex' : 1, '_id' : 0 }")
    Flux<Integer> findProfilerQuestionsAnalyticsIndices(String profilerId);

However, it clearly fails (org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Expected to read Document Document{{analyticsIndex=14}} into type class java.lang.Integer but didn't find a PersistentEntity for the latter!) because Mongo is returning the flux of projected documents and the application can't properly map them to an Integer. Changing the return type to a Flux<QuestionProfilerSolutionLineDocument> works, but then I have to map them once they're found.
Is there a way, preferably in Spring directly, to retrieve the values without their key?
